# Even width of Text and Textfield

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have a simple login form written in QML with a custom component, `MediumText`, and two `TextField`s. Unfortunately, I'm not able to properly align the elements, as shown by the following picture:

[image]

I want the labels to the left (`MediumText` type), as well as the `TextField` instances on the right, to take up the same amount of space so that they are correctly aligned. Can you suggest me an approach? Here is my current code.

MediumText.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.3

Text {
  clip: true
  font.pixelSize: 20
  font.family: "Liberation Mono"
  smooth: true
  font.bold: true
  wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
  opacity: 1
}
```

Login.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Rectangle {
    id:rootRect
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    Layout.preferredWidth: 480
    Layout.preferredHeight: 640

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        spacing: 16
        Row{
            Image {
                id: logoimage
                height: 135
                fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
                source: "images/logo.png"
            }
        }

        RowLayout {
            anchors.left: parent.left; anchors.right: parent.right
            spacing: 4
            MediumText { text: "Username: ";Layout.fillWidth:true; }
            TextField { id:usernameText; placeholderText: "username"; Layout.fillWidth: true;}
        }
        RowLayout {
            anchors.left: parent.left; anchors.right: parent.right
            spacing: 4
            MediumText { text: "Password:";Layout.fillWidth:true }
            TextField { id:passwordText; placeholderText: "password"; echoMode: TextInput.Password; Layout.fillWidth: true;}
        }
        RowLayout {
            spacing: 16
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            Button { text: "Login"; onClicked: {
                    console.log(mojoLoginLoader.visible);
                    mojoLoginLoader.visible=true;
                    passwordText.enabled=false;
                    usernameText.enabled=false;
                    //auth_controller.sayHello();
                    mojoRootViewHolder.source="Welcome.qml"
                }
            }
            Button { text: "Exit"; onClicked: auth_controller.sayNay() }
        }
    }
    CenteredLoader{visible:false; id:mojoLoginLoader}
}
```

Comment: Please fix all errors before posting code: `main.qml:53 CenteredLoader is not a type`

Comment: The same goes for resources which we don't have access to; replace any `Image` whose source points to a local resource with `Rectangle` if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `GridLayout` instead of building a grid by means of `ColumnLayout` and `RowLayout`.
By using the `GridLayout`, what you want is already guaranteed by the component.

Here is a full example from which you can start:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 500
    height: 500
    title: "Grid example"

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        spacing: 16
        Row{
            Image {
                id: logoimage
                height: 135
                fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
                source: "images/logo.png"
            }
        }

        GridLayout {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            columnSpacing: 16
            rowSpacing: 4
            columns: 2

            MediumText { text: "Username: "; Layout.fillWidth:true; }
            TextField { id:usernameText; placeholderText: "username"; Layout.fillWidth: true;}
            MediumText { text: "Password:";Layout.fillWidth:true }
            TextField { id:passwordText; placeholderText: "password"; echoMode: TextInput.Password; Layout.fillWidth: true;}
        }

        RowLayout {
            spacing: 16
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            Button { text: "Login"; onClicked: {
                    console.log(mojoLoginLoader.visible);
                    mojoLoginLoader.visible=true;
                    passwordText.enabled=false;
                    usernameText.enabled=false;
                    //auth_controller.sayHello();
                    mojoRootViewHolder.source="Welcome.qml"
                }
            }
            Button { text: "Exit"; onClicked: auth_controller.sayNay() }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did switch to a GridLayout as it made more sense for this use case, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

One fix that works is setting the `preferredWidth` property of the `TextField`:

```
MediumText { text: "Username: ";Layout.fillWidth:true;Layout.preferredWidth: parent.width/2}
```